# Defining fmap for a binary search tree

Tags: haskell, tree, functor

I'm working through the exercises in the book "Beginning Haskell." Exercise 4-8 is to make a binary search tree an instance of Functor and define fmap. This is what the tree looks like:

```
data BinaryTree a = Node a (BinaryTree a) (BinaryTree a) 
                  | Leaf
                    deriving Show
```

Because it is a search tree, all operations on the tree must maintain the invariant that all values in the left subtree are < the node's value and all values in the right subtree are > the node's value. This means that all values in the tree must be ordinal (`Ord a => BinaryTree a`).

Two questions:

1. Since `fmap :: (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b`, how do I enforce that `b` is also ordinal? If it didn't have to be a Functor, I could simply do `fmapOrd :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b`, but the Functor typeclass doesn't enforce the Ord contraints.
2. What does an efficient implementation look like? My first thought was to fold over the tree, and build up a new tree out of the mapped values. Unfortunately, I didn't get this far because of (1).

Comment: It would be nice if instances of TypeClasses could put stricter constraints on function arguments than the original declaration. It seems like this should be possible....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The point of `Functor`s and `fmap` is that it works for all `a` and `b` that can be stored in your data structure, just like `Monad` has to work for all types `a` as well.  Your `Functor` instance should look like

```
instance Functor BinaryTree where
    fmap f Leaf = Leaf
    fmap f (Node a l r) = Node (f a) (fmap f l) (fmap f r)
```

But if you then want to ensure that mapping over a binary tree keeps it balanced, then you need a function

```
balanceTree :: Ord a => BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a
```

You should be able to implement this function fairly easily with some googling, then you can define a specialized mapping function

```
binMap :: (Ord a, Ord b) => (a -> b) -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree b
binMap f = balanceTree . fmap f
```

And then you should ensure that you and the users of your library never use `fmap` (unless necessary) and instead use `binMap`.

Comment: `binMap` shouldn't need `Ord a`

Comment: Worse problem is that the result of `fmap` is not a search tree, so many functions defined for search trees won't work correctly, and users should simply _never_ use `fmap` for this type. The best way to ensure this is not to define `fmap` :)

Comment: @J.Abrahamson I only included it because OP wanted it, and sometimes including an extra condition, while not strictly necessary, can be useful in ensuring that the API is not abused.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to enforce ordering, then your binary tree as it is cannot be made into a functor, because - as you pointed out - the types don't match. However, while the tree can't be a functor over the *keys*, it can be a functor over the *values*, provided that there are separate type parameters for each. The standard `Data.Map` (also implemented as a search tree) works this way.

```
-- Now the "v" parameter can be mapped over without any care for tree invariants
data Tree k v = Node k v (Tree k v) (Tree k v) | Leaf
```

As to the implementation of `fmap`, your first thought is right. There is also a lazier way though, namely letting GHC derive the instance:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}

data Tree k v = Node k v (Tree k v) (Tree k v) | Leaf deriving (Functor)
```

It pretty much always matches your intents, just remember to let the last type parameter be the one you intend to map over.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not going to say I recommend what follows, but for completeness *it actually is possible to define such a Functor*.

The `Functor` typeclass demands that you can `fmap` *any* function into your `Functor`. This means, normally, that it's difficult to ensure invariants which demand typeclass instances. However, we can contort this situation quite a bit and actually end up getting away with a `Functor` instance. In practice, what it means is that we can use the type system to ensure that we we defer our rebalancing to times that are more convenient.

First, we'll introduce a demand on the above type. In particular, we'll give it a `Monoid` instance which maintains balance. This works out fine since `Monoid` doesn't require our container be polymorphic.

```
instance Ord a => Monoid (BalancedTree a) where
  mempty = Leaf
  mappend Leaf Leaf = Leaf
  mappend Leaf b    = b
  mappend b    Leaf = b
  mappend (Node a l1 r1) (Node b l2 r2) = ... -- merge and rebalance here
```

Now, using this instance we can write functions which correspond *almost* to a `Monad` instance for `BinaryTree`. In particular, we need it in order to combine our new trees as build using `bindBin`, the *almost* version of `(>>=)` on binary search trees.

```
returnBin :: a -> BinaryTree a
returnBin a = Node a Leaf Leaf

bindBin :: Ord b => BinaryTree a -> (a -> BinaryTree b) -> BinaryTree b
bindBin Leaf _ = Leaf
bindBin (Node a l r) f = bindBin l f <> f a <> bindBin r f
```

Then we introduce this very strange type (which requires the `RankNTypes` extension)

```
newtype FBinaryTree a = 
  FBinaryTree (forall r . Ord r => (a -> BinaryTree r) -> BinaryTree r)
```

There are many ways of thinking about this, but we'll just note that there's an isomorphism between `FBinaryTree a` and `BinaryTree a` witnessed, basically, by `returnBin` and `bindBin`.

```
toF :: BinaryTree a -> FBinaryTree a
toF bt = FBinaryTree (bindBin bt)

fromF :: Ord a => FBinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a
fromF (FBinaryTree k) = k returnBin
```

and finally, as `FBinaryTree` inherits some of the properties of the `Cont` monad or the `Yoneda` lemma type, we can define a `Functor` instance for `FBinaryTree`!

```
instance Functor FBinaryTree where
  fmap f (FBinaryTree c) = FBinaryTree (\k -> c (k . f))
```

So that now, all we must do is convert our `BinaryTree`s into `FBinaryTree`s, perform our `Functor` operations there, and then drop back down to `BinaryTree` as needed. Smooth sailing, right?

Well, almost. It turns out that there's a huge efficiency price we pay for this. In particular, it's easy to have exponential blowups occur when using types like `FBinaryTree`. We can avoid these by sending `FBinaryTree` through `BinaryTree` from time to time by using

```
optimize :: Ord a => FBinaryTree a -> FBinaryTree a
optimize = toF . fromF
```

which, as the type shows, requires us to have an `Ord` instance right there. In fact, the code will use the `Ord` instance there to perform the needed rebalancing.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, you do not need to make the constraint that either type is a member of `Ord`.  Functions like add, search, and remove will only work with members of `Ord`, but, for `fmap`, it is not necessary to compare.  There is nothing wrong with allowing users to convert trees from one incomparable to another.  It is just that he will not be able to call add, remove, or search on the resulting type.

As for your second question, my recommendation would be to use recursion.  The function would take a tree of type `a` and a function, and return a new tree with the function and return a tree with the function applied to the value and fmap applied to its children.  Here is a simple implementation:

```
fmap::(BinaryTree a,BinaryTree b)=>BinaryTree a->(a->b)->BinaryTree b
fmap (Node value left right) fun=Node (fun value) (fmap left) (fmap right)
fmap Leaf _ _=Leaf
```

I am not sure if my syntax is right, but you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

One more option is to make `Ord a` constraint part of the type using GADTs:

```
data BinaryTree a where
  Leaf :: BinaryTree a
  Node :: Ord a => a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a
    deriving Show
```

Now when pattern-matching on `Node` you can use the constraint.

```
fmap _ Leaf = Leaf
fmap f (Node value left right) = insert (f value) (merge (fmap f left) (fmap f right))
  -- assumes you defined insert and merge functions for search trees
```